# java.io.IOException with hudson

Tags: svn, hudson

I use Hudson, and source code is controlled by SVN.

When a new workspace checkout on slave, it displays:

```
hudson.util.IOException2:remote file operation failed
caused by :java.io.IOException:remote call on server1 failed
...
caused by:java.lang.OutOfMemroyError:java heap space
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check the "[I'm getting OutOfMemoryError](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/I%27m+getting+OutOfMemoryError)" Hudson page and see if one of the suggestions there can help.

> If your Hudson started choking with OutOfMemoryError, there are three possibilities.
>
> - Your Hudson is growing in data size, requiring a bigger heap space. In this case you just want to give it a bigger heap.
> - Your Hudson is temporarily processing a large amount of data (like test reports), requring a bigger head room in memory. In this case you just want to give it a bigger heap.
> - Your Hudson is leaking memory, in which case we need to fix that.

There were [bugs like HUDSON-1215](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-1215), but solved in recent Hudson version.

[This thread](http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/slave-abending-on-svn-checkout-td3458666.html) reports a similar issue.

> There seems to be something like that going on.
>   I also had SVN checkouts fail on one Mac slave.
>   After I added `-Xmx2G` on the slave startup options, the problem went away.
>
> Others please note that the JVM options appear under the node Configure screen under `[Advanced...]`

[image: JVM options on Hudson]